# Display an image of 1920x1170 / 183KB as BG using CSS

Tags: css

I want to display an image of 1920x1170 pixel / 183KB as a background image, here is my code

```
.bground{
      height:auto;
      left:0;
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      width:100%;

   }


<div class="bground" style="left:0px;">
<img src="Untitled-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

It displays the image alright, but the problem is that I can see only half the image, not full.  And when I right click, the menu says save image as, copy image, copy image url.  I expect reload page...etc....

How do I correct it.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: The top half, I want to see the full image on a 15.6" and 26" screen

Comment: already tried that height:100%, does not work, also, I think the image overflows the div, how do I contain it, without scroll bar

Comment: Are you saying you want the background to scale on a smaller monitor (or browser size)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 media queries to scale background images: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supersize-that-background-please/

Comment: The linked article also mentions a couple of workarounds using the `img` tag for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incomplete, and you probably should set the image as background image (not sure, you're not giving more detail about your situation).
Try

```
.bground{
      height:auto;
      left:0;
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-image: url(Untitled-2.jpg);
      background-position: left top; /* Adjust to liking */
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }

<div class="bground">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: @Jean can you add a screen shot or live link to your question? Also, your screen resolution is 1920 x 1170 Pixels or more, right?

Comment: Any way to upload the image here, so you get the feel of what I am trying to say

Comment: @Jean not here directly, no... Do you want to *scale* the image to your screen size?

Answer (score 0):

```
hmtl, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }
.bground {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(Untitled-2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

<div class="bground">
</div>
```

Your image was probably cut because <html> was not taking all the screen space.

Comment: You have to add height and width to HTML and BODY too.
I verified and it works, so if it doesn't for you, then there's another problem and you should give us more details.
A live page would be best.

Comment: The image is 1920x1170px, and using your code, the image is not displayed either

Answer (score 0):

hmtl, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }
.bground {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(Untitled-2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

this is right answer .........